# Simple nginx Dockerfile not working - localhost:8080 connection refused on local machine (ubuntu)

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

hey im trying to run a simple nginx dockerfile, but I cannot get it to work properly. Im working on Ubuntu 21.04 and I want to make the Hello-World.txt fiel accessable with http://localhost:8080/Hello-World.txt

My dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.19
COPY Hello-World.txt /usr/share/nginx/html
```

my Folder `ls`:

```
Dockerfile  Hello-World.txt
```

Thats how I build it:

`docker build  -t hue-a1 . --no-cache`

How I run it:

`docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 --name hue-a1_container hue-a1`

Output after I run it:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
```

I make sure the container is running:

```
c3db89349d16   hue-a1                          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 minutes ago    Up 8 minutes    0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   hue-a1_container
```

curl http://localhost:8080 leads me to:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

What am I missing ? I cannot reach it in the browser aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
I configured a `docker context` on my machine and had to change it manually to use the correct context...